# Finder's incorrect PDF Filesize

Tags: finder, macos, file

A few PDF files are showing with the incorrect filesize and I was wondering if there is any way to fix this.

E.g. opening a PDF file's properties is showing that the file is 394 KB, if I attach the file to an email or upload it by FTP somewhere else I get the file's real size which is 289 KB

This behaviour seems to be happening with any PDF file on my computer.
Is there a setting that can be changed or something to fix this?

This is happening for me on El Capitan 10.11.3

Answer (score 2):

This is typically caused by [resource forks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) that are local and don't get sent with the file in the email. You can view these and their sizes using ls in Terminal using:

```
ls -lah@ <filename>
```

or just leave filename blank to display this for the contents of the current directory.